# Морфемный и словообразовательный анализ слов "пастух, пастбище"

Tags: словообразование, морфемика, историческая-грамматика

**У Тихонова:** пасти ― паст/ух, пасти ― паст/бищ/е.

Как объясняется  наращение корня и суффикса?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, где тут вы видите наращение **корня**? Да и с суффиксом тоже не очень понятно. "бищ" это скорее два разных суффикса, первый (б) - встречается в таких образованиях, как свадь**б**а, стрель**б**а - и проч. Отсюда и пасти-пастьба-пастбище.

Comment: Меня интересует общая картина: как в школе разбирают эти слова. Понятно, откуда берется Б, но схема словообразования здесь "пасти - пастбище", поэтому Б относят к суффиксу.

Answer (score 1):

Основа этого слова, вообще говоря, вызывает большие вопросы — как с точки зрения истории языка, так и с современного положения. Откуда взялся этот морфоид *-т-* на конце основы, неясно. Шанский полагает, что от «утраченного **пастъ** 'пастух'», но решение едва ли верное: откуда тогда в других производных этот *-т-*? Неужели *пастьба, пастбище* — отыменные существительные? Конечно нет! Есть предложение Черных, связанное со смешением индоевропейских баз, — что ж, это выглядит правдоподобней, но от этого не становится менее загадочным.

В синхронии любое решение будет неидеальным. Я бы предложил такой вариант: пастух-ø, где основа непроизводна и нечленима. Аргументы:

1. Аналогичного суф. *-ух* в современном русском языке нет (исторически, похоже, *петух* — с той же проблемной *-т-*), а вычленять унификс бессмысленно — см. п. 2.
2. Закрыть глаза на элемент -т- никак нельзя (а Тихонов как раз взял и закрыл), в русском языке отглагольные имена так не образуются как ни крути. Должна быть основа *пас-*, а имеем *паст-*.
3. Вычленять уникальный аффикс *-тух* опять же бессмысленно и неэкономно, ведь в случае его выделения что делать с остальными производными? Выделять *-тбищ* в *пастбище*, *-тьб* в *пастьба*? Ни в коем случае.

Минусы — утрачивается мотивационная связь, которая, однако, семантически сохраняется (мы все-таки понимаем, что пастух — это тот, кто пасет).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне разбор у Тихонова кажется правильным: Т он относит к корню, а Б - к суффиксу. Я проверила эти слова по словообразовательному словарю Ефремовой, и вот что меня заинтересовало. Она пользуется терминами «словообразовательный суффикс или словообразовательная единица (формант)». Фактически это сложные суффиксы, в нашем случае на основе суффикса ИЩ это БИЩ и ЛИЩ.  Но Т она тоже присоединяет к суффиксу: пасти - пас/тух, при наличии "пастбища" это не очень удобно.

Comment: Интересен сам метод. Вот слова: жилище, хранилище, лежбище, стойбище, Если основа заканчивается на гласную и  суффикс на гласную использовать неудобно или если фонетика будущего слова неудобна, то применяется "подручный" материал: суффиксы Б, Л.  Аналогично со словами петух и пастух. Здесь Т можно просто позаимствовать из глагольного ТЬ (петь - петух),  но можно отнести к корню (пасти – пастух, для этого есть исторические предпосылки). В слове "пастух"  Т фонетически необходимо. Но вся эта кухня должна быть понятной, всё должно делаться и объясняться в открытую.

Comment: @Jasmin а почему Т фонетически необходима? Па**су**, не**су**шка — фонетически все разрешено.

Comment: Не пастух, а пасух? Не очень понятное слово. Если сравнить с несушкой, то здесь формант ПА похож на приставку, поэтому смысловые связи могут казаться  неясными.

Comment: @Jasmin я не размышляю сейчас о гипотетических формах. Дело в том, что если вы говорите о фонетической необходимости, то значит, что в СРЯ действует какой-то закон, какое-то правило, которое запрещает то или иное сочетание звуков. Иначе — это не фонетическая необходимость. Например, в русском сочетания звонких шумных перед глухими шумными в середине слова фонетически невозможно: *[p a l z t' í]. /z/ должна быть представлена перед [t'] глухим аллофоном, вот это — фонетическая необходимость.

Comment: @Jasmin более того, если вы считаете, что при словообразовании применяются «подручные материалы» — морфемы Б, Л и т. п., которые нужны лишь для устранения труднопроизносимых сочетаний звуков, то в этом суждении заключается серьезная ошибка. Любая морфема — двухсторонний языковой знак, который обладает не только материальным (звуковым) выражением, но и грамматическим/лексическим значением. Это значит, что «подручный материал» как минимум не морфемы, а нечто на них похожее — интерфиксы, межморфемные прокладки, морфоиды... есть много разных терминов.

Comment: Это не правило и не закон, а независимое развитие языка, обеспечивающее прежде всего ясный смысл слов и удобное их произношение. Именно это в приоритете. Вот по каким правилам делается перегласовка гореть - гарь, загореть - загар, рассмотреть - рассматривать. И о "подручных". средствах. Эти суффиксы имеют прямое отношение к словообразовательному гнезду. пасти - (пастьба) - пастбище, отсюда берем суффикс Б. жить - (жил) - жилище, здесь пригодился суффикс прошедшего времени Л. Нужно различать суффикс как значащую морфему (это суффиксы ИЩ, УХ) и словообразовательные (сложные) суффиксы ЛИЩ, БИЩ.

Comment: @Jasmin 1) так все равно — чего неясного и неудобного в «пасухе»? Формулировка «независимое развитие языка» прям ставит под сомнение все достижения исторической (да и не исторической) фонетики... Ваши примеры про «перегласовку», кхм, не в тему. Тут все вполне объяснимо (я не про орфографию, а про звуки) законами языка. 2) Постойте. Вы же писали: «Если основа заканчивается на гласную и суффикс на гласную **использовать неудобно или если фонетика будущего слова неудобна**, то применяется "подручный" материал: суффиксы Б, Л». А теперь говорите, что _б_ в _бищ_ — из предыдущего звена цепи.

Comment: Так все-таки произносить неудобно или же Б и Л — суффиксы, которые имели место ранее в словообразовательной цепи?

Comment: Пожалуй, мы очень увлеклись, наш вопрос - это куда отнести Б и Т и можно ли пользоваться термином "словообразовательный (сложный) суффикс. Я уже сомневаюсь насчет Т, отнесенного к корню.  Вспомнила, что есть группа приставочных глаголов, семантически близких к "пасти": запасти - запасать, опасаться, там Т в корне нет. В любом случае, спасибо за интересную беседу.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт о морфемном составе (а не о словообразовании), то у Тихонова так:

***пас/т/ух/; пас/т/бищ/е***

(Словарь-справочник по русскому языку. М., 1997).

В выпущенном чуть позже его "Морфемно-орфографическом словаре" (М., 2002) – так:

***пас/т/ух/; пас/т/б/ищ/е.***

===

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Из комментария **Jasmin**:

> У меня есть очень старый словарь Тихонова (1973 год), там у него
>   гнезда расписаны. В нем пасти ― паст/ух, пасти ― паст/бищ/е.

У меня под рукой словаря 1973 года нет, но смею предположить, что в нём написано не совсем так, как Вы воспроизвели. Скорее всего, у Тихонова там дано так: паст-**ух**, паст-**бищ**(е). Судя по его после вышедшим словарям, это не совсем деление на морфемы. В "Словаре-справочнике" 1997 года у Тихонова так: паст(и) -> паст+**ух**; пас/т/ух/.  Вначале даётся то, что Тихонов называет в разделе "Как пользоваться словарем" словообразовательной характеристикой слова, затем показан морфемный состав слова. В "Морфемно-орфографическом словаре" 2002 года Тихонов пишет, что "деривационные форманты, на словообразовательном уровне выступающие как цельные единицы, на морфемном уровне могут выступать как членимые единицы"…

Почему в слове *пастух* Тихонов выделил суффикс "т"? Не готов сейчас об этом говорить. Вижу лишь, что хорошего решения для этого слова пока не предложил никто из словаристов...

Comment: У меня есть очень старый словарь Тихонова (1973 год), там у него гнезда расписаны. В нем пасти ― паст/ух, пасти ― паст/бищ/е. У Ефремовой словообразовательным единицам дается характеристика, связанная с регулярностью и продуктивностью. Суффикс Т  применяется для образования причастий, а в слове пастух он откуда? У Черных это исторический суффикс (pa-t,  pa-st), и носителями языка он не воспринимается как действующий.  Чтобы выделить его в современном языке, нужно иметь словообразовательные схемы, в которых он участвует.

Comment: Jasmin: _У Ефремовой словообразовательным единицам дается характеристика, связанная с регулярностью и продуктивностью. Суффикс Т применяется для образования причастий, а в слове пастух он откуда?_ ===

Тем не менее в слове _пастбище_ Ефремова этот суффикс (-т-) выделила. А в слове _пастух_ – нет. По-моему, такое решение ещё больше вопросов вызывает.

Comment: У Тихонова это выглядит так: пасти, далее следует вертикальная черта и колонка  слов: пасти; пастьба;  пастбище -пастбищный; пастух - пастушок и т.д;  Ефремова тоже пользуется термином "словообразовательные форманты", но они могут быть сложными суффиксами (ЕННИК), состоящими из действующих суффиксов, а могут включать какую-либо фонетическую единицу, как  в схеме петь - пе/тух, пасти - пас/тух.

Comment: Jasmin: _У Тихонова это выглядит так: пасти, далее следует вертикальная черта и колонка слов: пасти; пастьба; пастбище -пастбищный_... === По-моему, Вы описываете "Школьный словообразовательный словарь" Тихонова. Но никаких слешей в нём, использованных в Вашем исходном вопросе и показывающих морфемное членение слов, нет. Да и вышел он не в 1973 году, а в 1978 году... Вы не ошиблись с годом издания в своём комментарии чуть выше?